# LDAP AD paging using java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I have few issues when trying to get members from a group in LDAP AD.

1) I need page size of 1000, but it is returning 1500 members (Is there any issue from myside or need to ask admins??)

2) Cookie value is always null and I am not sure what is missing. Cookie is null and resultpagesize is null

Please help me if you came across this issue and solved this

```
Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
LdapContext ctx;
byte[] cookie = null;
try {
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"cn=testaccount");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "passwd");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
String returnedAtts[]={"member"};
searchCtls.setSearchScope(2);
searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[] { new PagedResultsControl(1000, false) });
do {
    NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("", "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=testgroup))", searchCtls);
    while (answer.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult entry = (SearchResult) answer.next();
            String attrsValaues = entry.getAttributes().toString();
            System.out.println(attrsValaues);
        }
        Control[] controls = ctx.getResponseControls();
        if (controls != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(controls[i]);
                if (controls[i] instanceof PagedResultsResponseControl) {
                    PagedResultsResponseControl prrc = (PagedResultsResponseControl) controls[i];
                    cookie = prrc.getCookie();
                }
            }
        }
        ctx.setRequestControls(new Control[] { new PagedResultsControl(1000, cookie, false) });
    } while(cookie!=null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The range support is included out of the box in Spring LDAP 1.3.2 and higher. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/DefaultIncrementalAttributesMapper.html

Comment: Paging is for search results. Getting large attribute lists using range is not paging. Not nitpicking, just so you know were to look for answers.

Comment: yaa I agree with you ixe013....I am using spring-ldap-1.3.1 and not able to upgrade. So I am used a alternate method to get the results shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to fetch users without using cookie

```
boolean endString = true;
int loopValue = 0;
while (endString) {
    int startValue = loopValue * 1000;
    int endvalue = (loopValue + 1) * 1000;
    SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
    String[] returnedAttrs = new String[1];
    String range = startValue + "-" + endvalue;
    returnedAttrs[0] = "member;range=" + range;
    searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAttrs);
    NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("", "(&(objectClass=group)(cn=testgroup))", searchCtls);
    while (answer.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult entry = (SearchResult) answer.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getAttributes());
        if (entry.getAttributes().toString().contains("{member;range=" + startValue + "-*")) {
            endString = false;
        }
    }
    loopValue++;
}
```

Comment: it seems that this solution not work if the group has users in the number of multiples of 1000.
it return "{member;range=" + startValue + "-" + endValue 
and for next page throws:
LDAP: error code 1 - 00002121: SvcErr: DSID-031206B8, problem 5012  (DIR_ERROR), data 8995

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring PagedResultsDirContextProcessor

You need to make sure your LdapContextSource has setPooled set to `true`

```
final PagedResultsDirContextProcessor processor = new PagedResultsDirContextProcessor(1000);

while(processor.hasMore()) {
    ldap.search(base, filter, controls, mapper, processor);
}
```